# How to do Async Threading with Queue in TCP/IP connection

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, queue, python-3.7

I have reproduce (simplified) my client class to connect the Custom Application (vendor app) server in local Machine itself, the communication with client via TCP/IP protocol with standard structure (struct).

How to use Async with Threading, Queue module to improve performance of my code.

#### Reproduced CLIENT code is below

(SERVER is another app which is running in same PC)

```
import sys
import socket
import struct
from threading import Thread
import queue    
class client():
    def __init__(self,serverport,clientport):
        self._ip = ""
        self._srport = serverport
        self._clport = clientport
        self.connection = False
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,
                                  socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self._Que = queue.Queue()
        #Struct format unpacks
        self._sheaderupk = struct.Struct("<lh").unpack
        self._sbidofferupk = struct.Struct("<10sllllll").unpack
        self._sfeedupk = struct.Struct("<10sll25sllllllllllllllllllll10sl20sllll10s10s10s10sl20sll20sll").unpack
        #data dict
        self._Bidofferprice = {}
        self._Feedprice = {}            
    def _connect(self) -> bool:
        try:
            self._ip = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
            self.sock.bind((self._ip, self._clport))
            self.sock.connect((self._ip, self._srport))
            self.SOCK_con_status = True
            return True
        except Exception:
            print("NOT connected")
            return False
            
    def runclient(self):         
        while self.connection:
            recvbytes = self.sock.recv(6)            
            if recvbytes:
                hrecvd = self._sheaderupk(recvbytes)
                while True:
                    recvbytes += self.sock.recv(hrecvd[0]-6)
                    if len(recvbytes) == hrecvd[0]:
                        break
                self._Que.put(recvbytes)  
            else: pass
        
    def queing(self):
        while self.connection:
            try:
                bytrecv = self._Que.get()
                header = self._sheaderupk(bytrecv[:6])
                if header[1] == 28:
                    bidoffer = self._sbidofferupk(bytrecv[11:45])
                    self._Bidofferprice[bidoffer[0].strip(b'\x00').decode()] = bidoffer

                elif header[1] == 22:
                    tupfeed = self._sfeedupk(bytrecv[11:284])
                    self._Feedprice[tupfeed[0].strip(b'\x00').decode()] = tupfeed 
            except Exception: pass               
    def main(self):        
        self.connection = self._connect()
        Thread(target=self.runclient, daemon=True).start()
        Thread(target=self.queing, daemon=True).start()           
        
TT = client(8000,8008)
TT.main()
```

Once the client code connected and updating with data in the dictionary, then  other Threading functions (not posted here) uses the values and do some stuff. Hopefully there will be around 20 Threading running by using same data

Comment: Your code represents the server or the client?If your code represents the server then you have to `bind` to `self.srport`.And then you have to `listen` for connections.Your client will `connect` to your server.

Comment: It is client, the server app is different app which is running same PC in Windows

Comment: Then you don't bind to a socket ! Only the server is supposed to bind a socket.The client just connects and starts sending/receiving.

Comment: Yes your are correct but, I want to bind with known port, i.e

Comment: You need to `bind` only if you plan to `listen-for` and also `accept` connections on your client.Do you want your client to act also as a server ?

Comment: Ok I will remove the bind, I would like to have how to do the same with Async and threading